# Can an audio interface like the scarlet solo power a 250 ohms headphone like the DT 770 pro sufficiently?

Tags: homerecording

Can I use the scarlet solo paired with the DT 770 250 ohms to listen to recordings at sufficient volume and do things like audio monitoring at good volume levels?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, [Focusrite's recommendation is less than 200 ohms for USB-powered
interfaces](https://support.focusrite.com/hc/en-gb/articles/210708269-What-impedance-headphones-should-I-use-with-my-audio-interface-), which includes Scarlet solo. The interface just lacks voltage to drive high impedance headphones at full volume. It's up to you if it's loud enough.

Comment: I’ve experienced weak headphone output with beefier cans on USB powered interfaces in general in the past. Better to run the signal into a mixer or a headphone amp.

Comment: I think the “mobile” or “USB” isn’t really the point here. A USB device could have charge pump to provide voltage to drive high impedance headphones, Focusrite engineers just chose to design for lower impedance.

Answer (score 1):

In practise, anything with a dedicated ¼" headphone output is going to be designed to drive 250Ω headphones at comfortable listening levels.

You really only need to compromise to lower impedance if you need extra volume - eg a drummer tracking to a click track - would need 80Ω for that extra punch.

Low impedance headphones are for low output devices such as mobile phones etc.

From beyer's own [DT 770 page](https://europe.beyerdynamic.com/dt-770-pro.html)…

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on when you said   "You really only need to compromise to lower impedance if you need extra volume - eg a drummer tracking to a click track - would need 80Ω for that extra punch.", how does one compromise on lower impedance? I thought lower impedance would drive more volume so wouldn't a drummer technically be more comfortable at a lower impedance?

Comment: Yes, that's why the drummer's cans would be 80Ω rather than 250Ω to get the extra volume.

Comment: You've rather contradicted your reference in your advice!  The Scarlett Solo, as a USB-powered device, comes into the 'Mobile Devices' category.  And why do you say 'compromise on lower impedance' ?   Hi (or low) impedance isn't 'good'.   The right one is what matches your equipment.

Comment: Mobile == phone etc. A USB interface can get enough power from the USB bus to drive phantom & headphones, My own external USB interface has been happily driving my 250Ω DT 990's for a decade with no issues. Compromise to lower impedance by having to run the headphone out at almost zero volume.